# Integration tests work fine from flutter drive, but hang when entering text in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: flutter, dart, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I have the following sign-in test set up for my app:

```dart
testWidgets('sign in with email and password', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  app.main();
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));
  final emailInputFinder = find.byKey(Key('type-email'));
  final passwordInputFinder = find.byKey(Key('type-password'));
  final emailButtonFinder = find.byKey(Key('enter-email'));
  final passwordButtonFinder = find.byKey(Key('enter-password'));
  final dashboardFinder = find.byKey(Key('dashboard'));
  await tester.enterText(emailInputFinder, 'test.lab.user.01@...');
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));
  await tester.tap(emailButtonFinder);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));
  await tester.enterText(passwordInputFinder, '...');
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));
  await tester.tap(passwordButtonFinder);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));
  expect(dashboardFinder, findsOneWidget);
});
```

The hardcoded 3 second delay isn't ideal, but without it I can't run the tests using the driver.

Running on my local machine with the driver is fine. I use the command

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart
```

But when I upload the Espresso test to Firebase Test Lab and review the video, the sign-in screen loads up, but the first `enterText()` command seems to have no effect. Nothing is added to the text field, and the test just times out.

I have tried various combinations of `tester.tap()` and `tester.showKeyboard()`, but so far, nothing is coming up.

How can I get `enterText()` to work correctly in the Espresso environment supported by TestLab?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `binding.testTextInput.register()`:

```
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() as IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding;

// Necessary for being able to enterText when not in debug mode 
  binding.testTextInput.register();
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/89703) in the flutter repo about documenting this. Basically if you're not in  debug mode you have to call `binding.testTextInput.register()` in order for `tester.enterText` to work.

Comment: That is somewhat annoying. I will return to this and see if it works -- it looks like it's the answer.

Comment: Hope this fixes your issue (although a little late)